# Clear activity stack except first activity

Tags: android

This is the activity flow I want to accomplish:

**A** > **B** > **C** > **(finish B & C)** > **D**

The user can navigate from C back to B. But once I start D the user can only go back to A.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How does the user navigate from A to B, from B to C, and from B to D? Are there buttons on each activity which the user clicks? Also, how does the user indicate they are finished in activities C and D? Do they just click the Back button or is there another button in the UI that they will click?

Comment: Just call finish() on every activity when passing intent..and at `onBackPressed()` pass intent to activity you want to open..

Answer (score 0):

You may try like below.

Start every activity with `startActivityForResult` and send a value from activity **D**. Check the value in `onActivityResult` method of activity **B** and **C**. If you found that value then finish the activity and send result to its parent activity except for activity **A**.

Answer (score 0):

Can activity A be closed and reopened after? If so, then you can make it this way:

**A->B**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, BActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**B->C**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, CActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**C->D**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, DActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

**D->A**

Stack is cleared, so you have to override onBackPressed()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation but unfortunately the A activity can't be closed.